# Xcode 9 : Swift file is not created in custom folder structure

Tags: xcode, text-files, xcode9.2

I’m trying to add a new **Swift** file in my **custom defined folder structure** but it adds up **text file instead of swift file.** I’m using Xcode 9.2 and Swift 4 language.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Looks at your folder Color, Its Blue.

That means it's an actual **Folder**, not **Group Folder** Created in Xcode.

**Only Group Folder Created in Xcode 9 will option to choose a template in New File**

[image]

**Eg:** 
**Right Clicking the Yellow Folder (Group)**
[image]

**Right Click the Blue Folder** 
[image]
you can clearly see options provided by both are different

Right Clicking the TodoListViper (folder in Yellow Color) and Click New File ,  you will see the Choosing Template Option

Comment: Nope...I haven't drag-drop approach. Simply went into folder structure created a folder structure and then added into project by Add files/folder.

Comment: oh Okay, always try to create a folder as a group, Xcode will create a corresponding folder for you in the filesystem, bcos having folder and group will confuse the heck out of people lots of times.